# Perfect code and even minimum distance

Tags: coding-theory

I am reading up on perfect code and there's a statement that puzzles me a bit:

> We remark that the extended Golay code is not perfect (and indeed cannot be because d is even!)

This makes me wonder, can we make a generate statement: "if d(C) is even, then C is not perfect"? If yes, then what would be the proof for it? Could someone please give some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ denote two codewords at distance $d$, $d$ even. In $d/2$ places
of the $d$ places where $x$ and $y$ differ, flip the bits in $x$ so that they
match the bits in $y$. The result is a vector $z$ that is at distance $d/2$ from
both $x$ and $y$. How does that jibe with the notion of a perfect code
in which the Hamming spheres centered on each codeword are disjoint and fill the
space? Which Hamming sphere does $z$ belong to?

Comment: so z shouldn't belong to any sphere, because the radius of each sphere is $t = floor(\frac{d - 1}{2})$ and $t < d/2$. Is this correct?

Comment: But with a _perfect_ code, **every** vector belongs to one and only one Hamming sphere of radius $t$ (whatever $t$ is) centered at a codeword. So which sphere does $z$ belong to? The one centered at codeword $x$ or the one centered at codeword $y$ or to some other codeword $\hat{x}$ that is at distance **less** than $\frac d2$ from $z$? If you choose the last alternative, try and figure out if the distance between $x$ and $\hat{x}$ and between $y$ and $\hat{x}$ to see if both distances are at least $d$. Look at what the _triangle inequality_ has to say about the matter.

Comment: Okay, let me try again: since the radius of each sphere is $t = \lfloor \frac{d - 1}{2} \rfloor$ and so $t < \frac{d}{2}$ i.e: $z$ does not belong to spheres centered at $x$ or $y$. Since $C$ is perfect, every vector belongs to a sphere so let $z$ belong to a sphere centered at codeword $\hat{x}$ such that $d(\hat{x}, z) < \frac{d}{2}$. By the triangle inequality, $d(x, \hat{x}) \leq d(x, z) + d(\hat{x}, z) < d$ contradicting minimum distance $d$ (similarly for $d(y, z)$). And so $C$ cannot be perfect.

Comment: Also, I notice that if I draw it out, the spheres centered at $x$ and $\hat{x}$ are not disjoint.